# React-Native-Webview: Unable to connect to 10.0.2.2 via android emulator. The certificate authority is not trusted

Tags: react-native, android-studio, expo, react-native-webview

I'm new to android development and I'm beginning work on a new android app.  I'm currently testing out expo with react-native-webview in an android studio emulator while I wait on my employer to send me proper development devices.  I am testing setting up an iframe that renders our existing site in the app and everything was going smoothly until I tried to connect to the site being served from my local machine over https.  I saw [this issue](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/11058) on expos git page saying that they pulled [this fix](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/pull/1466) into their december release and it does seem to be working in all cases for me except when connecting to 10.0.2.2 over https.  I tried enabling the "Accept all certificates" option in android studio but that doesn't seem to have fixed it either.

These snippets all render ok

```
  <WebView source={{ uri: 'https://www.google.com/' }} />
  <WebView source={{ uri: 'http://10.0.2.2/website/' }} />
  <WebView source={{ uri: 'https://{alphaenvironment}.com/website/' }} />
```

While the following returns "SSL Error: the certificate authority is not trusted"

```
  <WebView source={{ uri: 'https://10.0.2.2/website/' }} />
```

This is my package json

```
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "jest --watchAll"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^12.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "5.11.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "~5.8.10",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "~5.12.8",
    "expo": "~40.0.0",
    "expo-asset": "~8.2.1",
    "expo-constants": "~9.3.0",
    "expo-font": "~8.4.0",
    "expo-linking": "~2.0.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.8.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.3",
    "expo-web-browser": "~8.6.0",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.8.0",
    "react-native-inappbrowser-reborn": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.1.9",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.15.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
    "@types/react": "~16.9.35",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.63.2",
    "jest-expo": "~40.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Can anyone help this noob?

Answer (score -2):

Check your computer's ip using the ipconfig command if it's windows or ifconfig if it's linux and replace 10.0.2.2 with it